# Trying to add css banner image so it can be changed easily on several pages

Tags: html, css

I don't want the image src to be on the html pages. I need to be able to change the banner image easily on the css and not have to change any info on every single html page. How can I do this?
There are also these two references already in the css:

```
}
.masthead .banner {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.masthead .banner img {
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Use [content:url("image.jpg")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content/)

```
<!doctype html>

<style>
.MyClass123{ content:url("http://imgur.com/SZ8Cm.jpg");}
</style>

<img class="MyClass123"/>
```

You can also do it with JS

```
getPropertyValue("--src")
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I can't figure out what's wrong. Does that style go onto the css? I even used your same MyClass123 as to not interfere with anything else. But — no good.

Comment: Your sample goes completely onto the html. I only want to reference the css on the html. The css is where I want the image to be referenced from so it can be changed easily. With your way, I would have to change every single html page in the site.

Comment: Ok..then move what's in the `<style>` tag to the stylesheet and target the `.MyClass123` from there.

Comment: I figured that's what I should do so I tried it and that worked. Thank you so much. The only thing I found was different was the size. So on each html where the image class ref. is- I added a new width and height to adjust it (because it was stretching across the top) Hopefully, now that's the last time I have to change EVRY html page in the site with the new img class.